# Xamarin Forms two way binding ActivityIndicator

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and I am using ActivityIndicator to say users that app is downloading the data. Problem is that I am using MVVM pattern and I need to set the values `IsRunning` and `IsVisible` from ViewModel. I have simple view:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HmtMobile"
         x:Class="HmtMobile.MainPage"
         Title="Přihlášení"
         >
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Margin="10" Spacing="15" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="ActivityIndicator" Color="Green" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Entry Placeholder="Uživatelské jméno" Text="{Binding UserName}"></Entry>
        <Entry Placeholder="Heslo" Text="{Binding Password}" IsPassword="True"></Entry>
        <Button Text="Přihlášení" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" BackgroundColor="#77D065" TextColor="White"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In the view constructor I am assigning the `BindingContext`

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new CredentialViewModel(this);
    }
```

Other properties works because when I want to login the properties returns the actual username and password but the twoway binding doesn´t. Properties are declared same so I do not understand why is this happening.

```
 private string password;
public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set { password = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private bool isBusy;

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return isBusy; }
        set { isBusy = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

I am using the simple Login method.

```
private async Task Login()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Delay(5000);
   }
```

THe `ActivityIndicator` is not appearing. Does anyone know why? OnPropertyCHanged is coded this way:

```
 public class Bindable
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it need to be TwoWay? For what you are doing the default (OneWay) is enough. Try to remove the TwoWay declaration and see if it works.

Comment: Are you sure? I need to set the value in VM and that populate it to view when I try to change it to OneWay it doesn´t recognize the change from code.

Comment: `OneWay` means that when you set it from the `BindingContext` it should update accordingly in the UI. If it is not updated correctly there probably is something wrong with your `NotifyPropertyChanged` mechanism.

Comment: The OnPropertyChanged is coded the way I showed in question update.

Comment: Is `INotifyProeprtyChanged` defined in your ViewModel ? Dunno why it is in a class calles Bindable ... Or is your ViewModel deriving from that ? simpla do it like this: `public class CredentialViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Because I am using OnPropertyChanged in multiple pages so I can define  it ones a use it in other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out based on Felix message. The problem was that in `Bindable` class I forgot to add : `INotifyPropertyChanged`.